# SharePoint 2010 web analytics not displaying any numbers - 6gb logging database

Tags: web-analytics

Hi
I have a sharepoint server 2010 project with Web Analytics Reporting enabled and I'm trying to figure out why nothing's being reported.

When I view the reports page, I get a bunch of zeros- no errors about it not running.

When I look in /14/logs, there are large .USAGE logs

When I open up SQL server mgmt studio, I see that the wss_logging database (renamed 'Usage', in our case) is at 6gb in size!!

I have read many links online about how to debug this, to no avail.  So, I'm hoping that by providing details here I can get other suggestions.

Help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't have the solution for you, but a personal experience: In my case, the WA stats stopped for about 14 days ago, and displayed all zeros since then. I checked the timer job in CA named "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import" and next to "Last run time" it said "N/A". So I chose "Run now", and then results started to appear again, on the day after (well, to be precise, I ran the job manually on the evening before, and the next morning I noticed new data). Still, in my case I have a field on every WA report saying "last updated: 21/03-2011", even though I see data from today. Q:

Answer (score 2):

Usage and Health data collection and Web Analytics are separate services in SharePoint. Usage and Health data collection will aggregate data sources (ULS log, Event Log, Perf Counters) depending on which timer jobs are activated and store the information in the logging database for 30 days (default). A separate job is responsible for post-processing usage information and writing it into the Web Analytics staging and reporting databases.

Here is a link to a good overview of how they work together by the ECM Team:

http://ecmteamblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/sharepoint-2010-web-analytics-under-the-covers/

You need to make sure that a) you have provisioned the Web Analytics service application, and b) that the appropriate timer jobs are enabled and set to correct schedule.